# "Liberation" and "free"

Tags: differences, synonyms

What is the difference between *liberation* and *free*?
Are *spiritual liberation* and *free will* the same?

Comment: Please make your question more clear, preferably with examples. Is this a question about philosophy or about language?

Comment: language, when to use which. what the difference.

Comment: Well, one is a noun and one is an adjective, so they are not exactly parallel. If you're asking for the difference, you must have a few examples where you think they are similar (and it's confusing which word to use): include those examples in your question. ("Spiritual liberation" and "free will" are philosophical concepts with a range of meanings; so unless you specify exactly what your intended meaning is, no one can say which word to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two questions. First: What is the difference in meaning between "liberation" and "free"?
Let's exclude the part of speech aspect. Free can be a verb or an adjective. Liberation is not a verb (the verb would be "liberate"). In terms of usage, liberation usually has a more formal or ideological meaning i.e. liberation from political oppression or liberation of prisoners-of-war.

Free may be substituted for liberated in the examples I just gave. It retains the same meaning. However, free has other meanings as well. It is often used to express a service or product that is gratis, provided at no cost, free of charge, no money required to obtain.

Regarding the second question: Spiritual liberation is the same as free will in some belief systems, but not in others. As  [ShreevatsaR](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/77/shreevatsar) stated, you must provide some clarification. The question, as it is currently phrased, is about philosophy or religion, not language.

Answer (score 1):

*Liberation* can mean:

- freeing a country, a city, or people from enemy occupation.
- releasing someone from a state or situation that limits freedom of thought or behavior.
- freeing someone from rigid social conventions, especially those concerned with accepted sexual roles.

*Free* can mean:

- Not under the control or in the power of another; able to act or be done as one wishes; subject neither to foreign domination nor to despotic government; not or no longer confined or imprisoned.
- Not physically restrained, obstructed, or fixed; unimpeded.
- Not subject to or constrained by engagements or obligations.
- Given or available without charge.
- Using or expending something without restraint; lavish.

*Spiritual liberation* and *free will* have different meaning, as *will* is generally understood as *a deliberate or fixed desire or intent*; *liberation* implicates a change of status (e.g., from *without freedom* to *with freedom*) that is not implicit in *free will*.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have sufficient context for a good answer, but in general, discussions about free will refer to the ability of a person to make a decision without being coerced into it, whereas spiritual liberation would suggest more of personal progression, from a state of spiritual repression to a freer state.

Lacking proper context, there not much else that can be said.